# Grayscale Bing Basemap - Is it possible in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, bing-maps

Is it possible to achieve a grayscale look for the Bing basemap in ArcMap 10?  I noticed that its possible with the maps hosted by ESRI since we can access the server that is hosting them.  I haven't been able to find anything on Bing.  Even using the OpenStreet Maps would be a great alternative, but again there doesn't seem to be an open server to use the trick posted on [ESRI's mapping blog](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/mappingcenter/archive/2011/11/18/Creating-a-Grayscale-Version-of-Any-ArcGIS-Online-Basemap.aspx).

**Edit**

It looks like this is currently not possible, so I'm accepting the "its not possible answer".  If this does become possible in the future please submit an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grey-Scaling can only be done when the data is a 'Mosaic Dataset' (in a geodatabase)

This can be done:
http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=2163

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000017000000.htm

The only other method is to Dim the BaseMaps

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful to know, hadn't used the Effects Toolbar before.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the map in Silverlight 3 then you can apply a custom effect on your layer: [Applying custom effects to Silverlight](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/11/applying-custom-effects-to-silverlight.html)

Comment: From the looks of this, it applies to web maps only.  I want to use this as a base layer in ArcMap, not a web map.